# Certain features of the app restricted to one country?

Tags: mobile, interaction-design, mobile-application, android

Suppose there is an app with three main core features. One of the core features can be used by users of any country and it will work fine.

The remaining two core features of the app may not work fine since the accuracy is not guaranteed and can show poor results.

**Option 1 :**

In this scenario, should one choose only that specific country where all the features will work

(or)

**Option 2**

For the users of other countries should one just display that this feature is currently restricted to this particular country?

Although you can cover more users with the second option,will it be a good user experience?

Which will be a good Design?

Answer (score 1):

Choosing between the two options is down to yourself - does the app need a higher volume of traffic? If yes, choose **Option 2** and use a design solution. If no, stick to **Option 1** which will be a better experience and less work involved for yourself.

If you go down the **Option 2** route, I'd suggest showing the user some kind of tool-tip or lightbox style feature to inform them that the feature may not be accurate for their current location and have a 'would you still like to continue?' button for added validation. This way, they are actively choosing to carry on using your app with the full knowledge it's not as accurate as they initially thought (also helps cover your back from a complaints point of view).

Comment: Sounds good about giving them a heads up, this way they can try all the features as well. Thanx :)

Answer (score 0):

Will user experience be good or not depends on how useful will be result of not accurate feature. If this result potentially will mislead user or deceive or negatively affect his decision - inaccurate feature should be removed. For example you showing weather as HOT and actually it is SNOWY - there is no sense in such feature. Although if you display -5 and actually it's -3 or -7 this will work in some cases.

As for design I think in some cases it's better indicate accuracy of result than accuracy of feature. We have no enough information on your case to give more exact advice.